# Extending Mage ImportExport te make it simpler

Tags: adminhtml, overrides, importexport, magento-1.9.2.1

I'm relatively new to Magento development and I was wondering if I could extend the Mage extension ImportExport Export block to make it simpler.

I want the user only to select the attribute-set as a filter and nothing more. Only the attributes of the selected attribute-set should be included in the export CSV.

I've been looking to override `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export_Entity_Product->export` but that would only be for the filtering it self.

I suspect I should override `Mage_ImportExport_Block_Adminhtml_Export_Edit_Form->_prepareForm` to hide the entity field and add the attribute-set select field?

Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could override but there is already an effective and widely used and actively supported magento community free extension which does the job better,cleaner and faster.

Check this github repository for more information

https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport

This module **AvS_FastSimpleImport** actually extends magento ImportExport model to make the import of products and customers much easier.

Hope am pointing you to the right direction !

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking to make the export process more simple. AvS_FastSimpleImport is for importing products.